# NullPointerException using append method on a view in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate data from database into a TextView using this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
 TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        String text =  cursor.getString(2);
       view.append(text);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

However I am getting a NullPointerException on this line:

```
 view.append(text);
```

and I am not sure about the reason as the view exists.

Comment: Paste the logcat error in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I am getting a NullPointerException on this line:
>
> view.append(text);
>   and I am not sure about the reason as the view exists.

If you are sure that `view` exists and is not null, then `text` has to be null. You could for instance rewrite it as `view.append(text != null ? text : "(null)");`

Comment: My apologies. The view did exist but in a different layout. I just had to modify setContentView(R.layout.main); to the appropriate layout. Your code helped me figure out this issue so I am going to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the directions of the database how my example look.
I do the same example, but with this difference:

```
**db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/cl.kl.muestrausuario/DataBases/BDUsuarios",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);**
Cursor c = db.query("usuario", new String[]{"regID", "nombre", "apellido"}, null, null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();

while (c.isAfterLast() == false)
{
    view.append("\n" + c.getString(1));
    view.append("\r" + c.getString(2));

    c.moveToNext();
```